# Problem formatting in VSCode with Prettier

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

```
textComp() {
return this.props.GMarcha
  ? this.props.english
    ? 'On'
    : 'Encendido'
  : this.props.english
    ? 'Off'
    : 'Apagado';
}
```

I have this function. When I use Prettier to format it it stays like this:

```
textComp() {
return this.props.GMarcha
  ? this.props.english
    ? 'On'
    : 'Encendido'
  : this.props.english
  ? 'Off'
  : 'Apagado';
}
```

Is there any way that when formatting it stays as I put it?

Comment: Having a consistent formatting is more important than the details of what that formatting is. The default for a popular editor is probably a good choice. If you ever work professionally you will likely have a style guide handed to you: you will rarely have the option to format your code strictly to your tastes. I'm not posting this as an answer because it doesn't really answer the question, but my *advice* is to avoid getting too attached to any particular format...but FWIW yeah that looks like a possible bug in the formatter.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but that particular thing seemed odd and I wanted to know if it was intentional or maybe some kind of bug and how to solve it